# How do I get Shotcut to work?

Tags: apt, xubuntu, dependencies

I've tried downloading from Software app and I've tried the portable version from their site and both throw this error when ran from console:

```
$ /home/user/Desktop/Shotcut/Shotcut.app/shotcut
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"
in "".

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, wayland-egl, wayland, xcb.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I've also tried running `sudo apt install xcb` which still provides the error when trying to start Shotcut.

I've tried installing Shotcut through `sudo apt install shotcut` but the package can't be found.

I'm running Xubuntu 16.04 which is fully up-to-date. I can't use a newer version of Xubuntu since I'm using a Lenovo laptop which is blocked from receiving OS updates due to a BIOS breaking issue caused by newer version.

---

Update

I've tried running `sudo apt install --reinstall libxcb-image0` which hasn't solved the issue. Which I found [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/777518/823065).

I came across deleting `libstdc++` from `/lib/` but I don't know if this is a safe option since I don't know if this will break the OS or other applications. Which I found [here](https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/issues/1385#issuecomment-314894980).

Comment: Please try researching the issue, and if you don't find anything useful, [edit] your question to explain what you found and how it didn't work. (See [ask].) I did a quick search and found a few related questions, including this one, which seems useful: [Qt5 apps won't open on one computer](https://askubuntu.com/q/777205/301745)

Comment: Forgot to mention, I searched the error message `This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "".`

Comment: I did some research but hadn't had any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by running `sudo apt install libxkbcommon-x11-0` into the Terminal to install a missing dependency.

I couldn't get any help here. So I decided to post the issue to Shotcut [github](https://github.com/mltframework/shotcut/issues/545) since time was at the essence.

Hopefully this'll help others with the same problem in future.